# How to model multilingual entities in relational databases

Tags: database-design, relational-database, multilingual

If we are going to develop a multilingual application, shall we store translations in **resource files** or the **database**?

Suppose we choose to do it in the database. Is there a standard way to model multilingual entities in the **Relational Model**?

### 1. One Big Translation Table

We can store all the translations in one table and use **language-neutral keys** for the attribute values.

Person (**SSN**, FirstName, LastName, Birthday)

Translation (**key**, **langid**, translation)

### 2. One Translation Table For Each Entity

Person (**SSN**, Birthday)

PersonML (**SSN**, **LangId**, FirstName, LastName)

I prefer this approach. It is really a **1:N relationship**.

#### Problem

It seems multilingual columns cannot be used to form a **Primary Key**.
Let's assume every person has a unique name, then (FirstName, LastName) can be used as the primary key.

Person (**FirstName**, **LastName**, Birthday)

However, when taking multilingual into account, (FirstName, LastName) cannot identify a person.
Apparently we can't add LangId to form a primary key.

Person (**LangId**, **FirstName**, **LastName**, Birthday)

In this case, one person would be stored in multiple rows and the non-key columns would be duplicated.

**Do we have to use *language-neutral columns* for Primary Keys?**
When there are no such columns, shall we use a **surrogate**?
I have been told that surrogates should not be used blindly and I strongly agree.

---

## Update 1

In the example, I assume *FirstName* and *LastName* are subject to localization.

If there is always some attribute like SSN for every entity, the second approach makes more sense.
However, some valid Primary Keys may become invalid if they contain columns that are subject to localization.

### Another Example

Every company has a unique name, so CompanyName can be used as the Primary Key.

Company (**CompanyName**, ...)

When it comes to localization, company name cannot be used as a primary key. We have to *invent* some *code* to represent the company.

Does it mean localization doesn't fit in the Relational Model?

---

## Update 2

### 3. 1:N Relationship Between Default Language and Other Languages

Users may perceive the company table as:

Company (**CompanyNameEnglish**, CompanyNameFrench, CompanyNameSpanish, ...)

Of course there are repeating groups, so it breaks 1NF.

Improved:

Company (**CompanyNameEnglish**, ...)

CompanyNameML (**CompanyNameEnglish**, **LangId**, CompanyName)

The problem is we have to provide the a default (English) Name even if it is not required by the user.
Some users may provide English names, others may provide French names ONLY.
Is this requirement too contrived?

### 4. DBMS Localization Support

[PerformanceDBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484814/performancedba) brought this up in his comment.
I will do more research on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Globalization of Database Stored Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045105/globalization-of-database-stored-values)

Comment: From your examples it's completely unclear *what* in your data model is subject to translation. Rather, it looks more like a "what's a good primary key"-like question. Please edit your post with *specific* info on your data model and columns subject to localization.

Comment: Assuming SSN stands for Social security number (and should be unique), it seems a natural choice for a primary key. in translation tables just add the language identifier to it to create a primary key.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. You are right. SSN is a more natural primary key in this case - bad example.

Comment: @OndrejTucny. Indeed, it's more like a "the impact localization has on primary keys" like question.

Comment: (a) if you want an RDB you can't **invent codes**, the keys must be *made up* from the data (b) Localisation has nothing to do with the *RM*, it is an implementation concern.  Get a SQL platform, localisation is standard these days (c) if you have localisation "issues", it is because you don't have a [i] commercial server.  Whatever code you write for your NONsql will be non-portable, you will have to replace it when you get an [i]  (d) Do store everything in the database (e) I am not sure that you really understand my answers, you are still asking how to break the rules.

Comment: (e) LangId is an attribute of Person, not necessarily part of the Relational key, it is 1::1 with the Person PK.  Now if you do **not** have a real SQL platform, sure, you might have to handle laocalisation in every code segment, and then to carry the LangId throughout, sure, you can make in part of the PK, but that is incorrect (f) if (SSN) or (LastName,FirstName) is unique, then that plus *anything* is also unique.  The addition is superfluous.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA. I have been thinking about how to choose a primary key and I happened to notice the product I am currently working on handles translations in the database and allows users to change translations in the UI. The db uses surrogates for almost every table. It is a commercial database but doesn't take advantage of the localization support and the Relational Power of the server.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA. Also, some web frameworks handles translations in XML files. There are so many choices to implement a single feature.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA. I think the Relational Model (First Order Predicate) can express everything, including translations. How shall we handle translations using relations?

Comment: (g) *so many choices [ways] to implement a single feature*.  Sure, but only a few are correct.  And few of those are rock-solid, such that, once implemented, you will never have to write it again, or fiddle with bugs and limitations.  Look at Sybase, IBM/DB2 & MSSQL for the correct, standard, method.  Localisation is part-server and part-client implementation. (h) Your last comment is good, it scopes the entire question text, and now it can be answered.  But we have to take it that you have a non-SQL, primitive, sub-standard platform. (i) Not *translations* but LangId text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81166/discussion-between-performancedba-and-dzhu).

Comment: Try the chat room again.

Answer (score 1):

*"I have been told that surrogates should not be used blindly and I strongly agree."*
I also agree with that, using anything *blindly* is never a smart choice.

**However,** not every time you use surrogate key it is done blindly.
Keep in mind that a primary key is not the only way to ensure uniqueness. Most if not all relational databases offers unique constraints and unique indexes, and it should be used wisely.
In fact, when storing multilingual data in translation tables, using a surrogate key might be better then using a natural one. [read this article](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html) for a good comparison between natural and surrogate key strategies.

To answer your question, I would go with a translation table for each entity, keeping only the entity non-textual data in the main entity table (such as birth date and gender in your person's example), and keeping the textual data in the translation table, having it's primary key composed of the language id and the entity table primary key.
Note that the primary key of the entity table in this case must be non-textual, and not language-depended.

Comment: *a primary key is not the only way to ensure uniqueness* is confused. Could you please clarify the statement, and perhaps give an example.  The *RM* requires that Keys are made up from the data, and of course that is the only method of providing uniqueness of **rows**.  You might be assigning surrogates as "primary key", but that does not provide uniqueness of **rows**, and the result is a Record Filing System without Integrity, particularly Relational Integrity (as distinct from Referential Integrity).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Ambler or his advice, it is full of errors, and ignorant of the *RM*.  There is no "Surrogate or Natural" argument or debate to be had.  The result of his advice is non-relational.  Using it reduces the credibility of your answer.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: read the next sentence: " Most if not all relational databases offers unique constraints and unique indexes, and it should be used wisely." Keeping a unique constraing or index on columns that need uniquness is the way to keep row uniqness whnn using a surrogate key. I don't agree with your statement that a key must be made out of data. I have beed working with a lot of databases that was designed with natuarl keys and with surrogate keys, They both have advantages and disadvantages.

As to your second comment, I don't even know what "Ambler" is, so I can't reference it.

Comment: (a) No problem with the *reading*, it appears the sentence is the same as the last time I read it (b) It doesn't matter what you think; or what I think; or if you agree with me, what matters is what Dr E F Codd wrote in the *Relational Model*.  That demands a Key must be made up from the data. If you don't have them, you do not have (i) Relational Keys or (ii) a Relational database. (c) The link that *you* gave is for a page written by Scott Ambler.  He is famous for spreading the "denormalise for performance" myth, for decades, and then switching to Normalised, for Agile, and being unable to

Comment: ... state his change.  The page is full of errors, half-truths, and misrepresentations.  Ambler is famous for his superficial understanding of whatever he postulates about.  Fowler is the same. (d) Surrogates vs Natural is **not** an either/or proposition. Read the surrogate-key wiki, it is half-right, and the right half proves it. (e) Your statements re *working with databases", taken with your other statements, means that they are not Relational databases.  Therefore you would not know what you are missing, so your opinions about it are ...

Comment: @performancedba: I really don't know what is it that you want. I've worked before on multilingual databases and the way I've suggested is easy to work with, fast and safe. If you think you can answer the question better, then by all means go ahead and post an answer. If you think surrogate keys is such a terrible idea, please do share why you think that.

Comment: I have answered the question in my comments to dzhu.  *Srrogates* Open a new question re surrogates, post the "advantages" and disadvantages, and I will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is moot : if you decide to store your translations in "resource files", then that set of resource files ***IS*** the database (or part of it).

The more relevant questions to answer are, e.g. : who is the owner of the translations (i.e. are the translations integral part of the software package or not - can end users customize them) ?  The answers to questions such as those will drive whether your translations can go as resource files shipped with the binaries or not.

I'm not giving any real answer, because the only one who can know the decisive factors is you.  I'm just pointing out the deeper kind of questions to be answered which will make it clear.

Comment: I admit the mootness of the question. Good point about *that set of resource files IS the database*. I also have confusion about using config files or storing configurations in the database. Broadly speaking, files ARE databases. Given that **relational** databases provide **Access Path Independence**, I prefer the database approach. In a product I am working on, there are hundreds of config files. It's a pain to work with them.

Comment: I know the feeling.  But SQL is so darn crippled that working with databases managed by a 'true' DBMS is often not much less of a pain either.

Comment: @dzhu.  To be clear, RDBMS does not *provide* Access Path Independence, or an *RDB*, that is something that you implement, after getting educated via the *Relational Model*, and you use the RDBMS to implement the method.  SQL isn't "crippled".  Of course if you implement a non-RDB, a Record Filing System, of course, the navigation is crippled, but that is not SQL.  Additionally, some people just don't know how to use it.